# Scala: How to Unit Test a function I have which makes a call to internal non-exposed API but in same service mesh call using mock/stub?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking

i have a function which makes a call to an api which is not externally exposed, but is present in same service mesh as the function.

lets say something like below.

```
func internalApiCall(payload: String): Unit = {
    request = buildRequestForApi(payload)
    response = (new URL(service.namespace.svc.cluster.local:8080/path)).openConnection().asInstanceOf[httpURLConnection]
    assert using response code
}
```

I need to write unit test for this, how can i do it? is it possible through mocking and if it is , how can we mock since the API it is calling is written in different language (Golang).

i need to mock the service but it is not externally exposed, need solutions on this.

Comment: It's not clear your question. If i understand correctly, you have a service A which calls a service B. Service A is written in scala, service B in Go. You want to test the flow of service A (scala) that calls service B (Go). If that is the case, you can mock the client that calls service B to test service A isolated. Other option could be use a real client to call a service mocked, or start a real service. I think the communication is through http, so, it doesn't matter in which language is written service B.

Comment: If my guess is not correct, please edit your post trying to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or more details about what you have and what you expect. The code provided doesn't look like scala code

Comment: Hi @GastonSchabas , yes thats exactly what i need, however the service B written in golang is not externally exposed, it is an internal service, how to test in thT CASE.

Comment: The provided code seems to be written in golang. Could you edit your post and show how the service call is written? There are different ways of testing based on what you need

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite your function to use a "client" instance to make the call rather than the `URL` directly.
Something like this, perhaps:

```
trait InternalApiClient { 
   def getStuff(endpoint: String, request: Request): Response
}
object InternalApiClient extends InternalApiClient {
   def getStuff(endpoint: String, request: Request) = {
     val con = new URL(endpoint)
       .openConnection
       .asInstanceOf[httpURLConnection]
     send(con, request)
     receive(con)
   }
}


class MyClass(client: InternalApiClient = InternalApiClient) {
   def internalApiCall(payload: String) = {
    val request = buildRequestForApi(payload)
    val response =  client
       .getStuff("service.namespace.svc.cluster.local:8080/path", request)
    doStuffWithResponse(response)
  }
}
```

Then you can write unit tests like this:

```
val client = mock[InternalApiClient]
val testMe = new MyClass(client)
when(client.getStuff(any, any)).thenReturn(someResponse)

testMe.internalApiCall("some payload")

verify(client)
  .getStuff("service.namespace.svc.cluster.local:8080/path", expectedRequest)
```